# How would I send a message to a random channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that will send a random message to a randomly selected channel when a user sends a specific message.

I have no idea how to approach this problem beyond getting all of the channel ids and manually adding them to a list, then randomly selecting from this list, but there are some very big problems with this approach and it just wouldn't work. I've tried looking through the documentation, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do what I want.

In short: I need a way to automatically collect all of the channel ids in the discord server, add them to an empty list, then be able to send a message to a randomly selected channel in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why there is a "big problem" with the way you described. Below is a short snippet that would do exactly what you described:

```
import random
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # assuming the bot is connected to only one guild
     guild = client.guilds[0]
     await random.choice(guild.text_channels).send("message goes here")
client.run(token)
```

It can also be achieved with the commands extension with relatively little modification of the above snippet.