# Send a message in a random channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot

The setup: I've made a bot to interact with users on my server. One of the features I've added is the game of Marco-Polo. When a user sends "Marco", the bot responds with "POLO...".

The problem: When the bot responds with "POLO...", it responds in the *same* channel as the original message. I, however, want the bot to respond in *a random channel within the server*, that sends the user looking for it.

I've searched online for the answer as well as in discord.py, but I haven't been able to find it. However, I'm new to Python and coding altogether, so it could very well be that I am simply missing something or that it's not possible, LOL.

Here is the code for the Marco-Polo game:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

msg = message.content
time_seconds = 1    

if msg.lower() == 'marco':
    time_seconds = 5
    await asyncio.sleep(time_seconds)
    await message.channel.send('POLO...')
```

Comment: You probably want `random_channel = random.choice(message.channel.guild.channels)

await random_channel.send("POLO...")`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844616/how-would-i-send-a-message-to-a-random-channel. The answer there doesn't answer this. It's valid Python, but it sends a message to *a random channel in the first guild of the bot*. This apparently asks to send a message to *a random channel in the guild the message's sent in*. Vote to reopen, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter version, using [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) again:

```py
import random
#random_channel = random.choice(message.channel.guild.channels)
random_channel = random.choice(message.guild.channels)
await random_channel.send("POLO...")
```

This will send the message in a random channel from *all* the channels in [the guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild), including channels it can't send in, for example, [`StoreChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#storechannel), [`CategoryChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#categorychannel), etc. (all the channels in the guild: all the [`GuildChannel`s](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel), whether [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) or not)

This probably will work:

```py
random_channel = random.choice(message.guild.textchannels)
await random_channel.send("POLO...")
```

...as it gets a random channel from all the [`TextChannel`s](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel) in the guild.

Also, you don't need to *install* `random` (like `pip install random`) as it's a built-in Python package.

Comment: OK, This works. Partially. It did come up with an attribute error: 'CategoryChannel' object has no attribute 'send'. When I typed Marco again, it worked in a separate channel, so I'm assuming that it's randomly choosing a channel that it can't send messages in, like the Voice chat channel. Is there a way I guess that I can selectively choose which text channels it is allowed to randomly choose?

Comment: @LeoneVarando, yes, will update it. I can't test it right now, though.

Comment: Ok. Looked through discord.py and (message.channel.guild.text_channels) seems to have done the trick! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LeoneVarando, also, the `.channel.` is redundant, as `message` (the context - that's why it's also named 'ctx') itself has the `guild` parameter; so, `message.guild`, no need `message.channel.guild`. *This will work even if the channel the message is sent in is deleted before the bot executes this code and the server responds to it.* Okay, that's too much, LOL.

Answer (score 1):

`message.channel` gets the channel that the original message was sent in. Try this code to send in a random channel:

```
#Get list of all text channels
text_channel_list = []
for channel in message.guild.text_channels:
    text_channel_list.append(channel)
#pick random channel and send
channel = random.choice(text_channel_list)
await channel.send('POLO...')
```

Try this, and let me know if it works. You will need to put `import random` at the top.

P.S. This should get *all* channels, which means that if you have some private channels, the bot still might send the message in it. If this will be an issue, we will need to get which channels the user that sent the original message has access to, and only send it in those. Let me know if that is necessary.

Comment: I suggest you roll back your answer to the original version, as it's more elaborate and may work differently in some cases. I guess you can catch exceptions if they fail too (with your method), so it probably covers more. As the OP said, some errors may come up with my answer. I just posted *a shorter version*. You changed it to mine, so your answer is not much different from mine other than the explanation. I'll re-upvote it if you change it back.